# Simplify the proposition ¬(p∧q)∧(p∨¬r)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can not come up with anything concrete,

$$¬(p∧q)∧(p∨¬r)$$

Thanks!

Comment: You can jigger your expression with the DeMorgan laws, but your result won't be any simpler than what you started with.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+for+%5BNOT(p+AND+q)+AND+(p+OR+(NOT+r))%5D

Answer (score 2):

Nnn...nope, that's about as simple as you will get.

Use deMorgan's Negation and you obtain CNF (Conjunctive Normal Form).

$$\lnot(p\land q)\land(p\lor\lnot r) ~\iff~ (\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land (p\lor\neg r)$$

Answer (score 0):

According to De Morgan's Law,

$\neg(p\cap{q})\cap(p\cup\neg{r})\equiv(\neg{p}\cup\neg{q})\cap(p\Rightarrow{r})$.
Look up for the Truth table, that will give you a better clue on how to approach such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution of the form $p \circ q \circ' r$ needs parenthesis, and this means that we are effectively looking at $p \circ'' s$ which isn't complex enough to return the values required.